# Why doesn't my CSS border appear when using internal styles?

Tags: html, css

I used internal CSS for text border but this doesn't work

```html
<h1 style="border-top: 5px; border-bottom: 10px; border-right: 15px; border-left: 20px;">Hi there!</h1>
```

Comment: There's more to a border than size. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `border` property requires a `border-style` property. Add `border-style: solid`

```html
<h1 style="border-top: 5px; border-bottom: 10px; border-right: 15px; border-left: 20px; border-style: solid">Hi there!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the border color

```html
<h1 style="border:solid #000000;border-width: 5px 15px 10px 20px;">Hi there!</h1>
```

Comment: Border color doesn't matter. `border-style` is the issue.

Comment: Since I used the border shorthand, solid is already defined and I don't need to specify the border-style.

Comment: I know this. Your shorthand does include `border-style`. The issue still stands that the issue isn't `border-color`...it's the fact that OP did not include `border-style` which is the issue - in shorthand or in long form.